# add_filter not working inside if function

Tags: filters

I want to edit the content before save to database for the first time only when add a new post, so i check the path if it's at the post-new.php i want to apply the filter, but it's not working. anyone know how to solve this ?

```
$pagePath = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
$pagePath = $pagePath['path'];
$pagePath = substr($pagePath, 1);

if($pagePath === 'wp-admin/post-new.php'){
    function my_filter_function_name( $content ) {
        return $content . 'text before save to db';
    }

    add_filter( 'content_save_pre', 'my_filter_function_name', 10, 1 );
}
```

Comment: Use `$page_now` or current_screen() to know which page is running, to be sure that the filter can fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to write this too much code.

```
$pagePath = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
$pagePath = $pagePath['path'];
$pagePath = substr($pagePath, 1);
```

you can easily get current page path by calling global variable **$pagenow**.

```
global $pagenow; // return 'post-new.php'
```

Instead of using `content_save_pre` filter you can do this same with `wp_insert_post_data` filter more easily. try out this.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'appendContent', 99, 2 );

function appendContent( $data, $postarr ) {  

       // Retrieve referer path of current page through wp_get_referer(). 
       $referer = basename( wp_get_referer() );  // post-new.php

       if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $postarr['ID'] ) && $referer == 'post-new.php' ) {

             $data['post_content'] = $data['post_content'] . ' text before save to db';
        }
    return $data;
}
```

*`wp_insert_post_data` is called by the wp_insert_post function prior to inserting into or updating the database.*

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your logic to check if it is first time. If your logic is correct, if condition should be inside the filter function.

```
$pagePath = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
$pagePath = $pagePath['path'];
$pagePath = substr($pagePath, 1);


function my_filter_function_name( $content ) {
    if($pagePath === 'wp-admin/post-new.php')
    {
        return $content . 'text before save to db';
    }
}

add_filter( 'content_save_pre', 'my_filter_function_name', 10, 1 );
```